# How to call my own Python function inside R?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have a problem with R and Python now. I have a function in Python that is working fine. I need it to do the rest of my work in R, because it's easier to do it there with the help of some libraries, but there's no way to call my .py file with reticulate.

I'm using RGui (32-bit) (pre-installed Python in my company's laptop is 32-bit.), R Version 3.5.3 and Python Version 3.7.3.

I've tried calling my function from a .py file with reticulate, didn't work. Thought it could be because of the path, but I moved my .py file to several folders and I'm still getting the same error.

```r
library(reticulate)

use_python('/Users/Nikolasp/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32', required = TRUE)

source_python('my_script.py')
```

Instead of being able to just run my Python function, I always get that same error message:

> Error in sys$stdout$flush() : attempt to apply non-function

Comment: A  possible solution is to install this version of reticulate `devtools::install_github("erikli/reticulate")`, as described at this link https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/584